# How to find the reduced row echelon form of a matrix in Maxima?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, maxima

I know that Maxima allows you to bring a matrix to a *row echelon form* through the function [`echelon`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_23.html#echelon), but is there a way to bring a matrix to ***reduced row echelon form***?

Answer (score 3):

Try these two methods:

1) Here's a custom plugin called "Matrixtools": http://shallice.com/wordpress/maxima-plugins/ called `redech(M)`.

2) Here's a Rosetta Code example of the `rref` function:

```
rref(a):=block([p,q,k],[p,q]:matrix_size(a),a:echelon(a),
    k:min(p,q),
    for i thru min(p,q) do (if a[i,i]=0 then (k:i-1,return())),
    for i:k thru 2 step -1 do (for j from i-1 thru 1 step -1 do a:rowop(a,j,i,a[j,i])),
    a)$

a: matrix([12,-27,36,44,59],
          [26,41,-54,24,23],
          [33,70,59,15,-68],
          [43,16,29,-52,-61],
          [-43,20,71,88,11])$

rref(a);
matrix([1,0,0,0,1/2],[0,1,0,0,-1],[0,0,1,0,-1/2],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0])
```